# Is it possible to write to Command Prompt with python?

Tags: python, cmd

Im opening Command Prompt with

```
os.startfile('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe')
```

and after opening the program id like to write the python file for it to run

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python>examplefile.py
```

when python opens the command prompt it starts with

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python>
```

so I would just need to add on the file to the end of the line and run it, is this possible?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The approved way to start up a subprocess is to use the `subprocess` module. There is also `os.system()` but it has been deprecated for decades. But if you want Python program A to run another Python program B, the way to do that is to have A import B, and then call a function inside B. That function can be anything you like, including all of the module-level code in B.

Comment: Does this work? `os.system('cmd /K "examplefile.py"')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `os` module to open cmd and the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module for writing in `cmd`

```py
import os
import keyboard
import time

os.system("start cmd")

# Because we don't want the `keyboard` module to write before cmd gets opened.
time.sleep(0.1)

keyboard.write("Anything you want")

# keyboard.press_and_release("enter") # pressing enter key
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) (this [`link`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) is for `2.7` documentation)

Otherwise `import`ing `keyboard` and using `keyboard.write("python3 myfile.py")` should work.